# Three JS find a point on plane knowing an origin point and the distance

Tags: three.js

I found the coordinates of the origin point from the intesection between a plane and a vector.

How can I find the coordinates of a second point on the plane knowing only the distance on the two axes that the second point should have

[image: Example]

Comment: Would be better to provide an explanatory picture, at least.

Comment: @prisoner849 Correct. <img src="https://www.hmsit.it/images/Immagine.png" width="100" height="100">. Having the point A coordinates, i would find to point B always on the mesh.